# In Julia assign the diagonal values of a matrix, get "error in method definition"

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I want set the diagonal elements of a matrix as 1, so I use `diag()` function, but I got error.

```
aa=rand(3,3);
diag(aa)=ones(3)
```

> error in method definition: function LinAlg.diag must be explicitly
>   imported to be extended

I also try to use `diag(aa)=[1,1,1]`, but it also seems not work.
How can solve this problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, `diag(aa) = ones(3)` is Matlab syntax and doesn't work as you would think.  In Julia, it is a method definition for `diag`, which is why you get that error.  You have to use indexing using square brackets, as in C-style languages.  (And maybe read about the [differences from Matlab](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/index.html) to avoid future surprises.)

To answer the question, you can use [`LinearAlgebra.diagind`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.diagind) to get the indices of the diagonal, and assign `1` to them by broadcasting:

```
julia> diagind(aa)
1:4:9

julia> aa[diagind(aa)] .= 1
3-element SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Tuple{StepRange{Int64,Int64}},true}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0

julia> aa
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0       0.726595  0.195829
 0.37975   1.0       0.882588
 0.604239  0.309412  1.0
```

Comment: I'm a little confused that when you input "diagind(aa)",it return"1:4:9", why it's not "1:5:9", I want to know the rule of index.

Comment: Since your matrix has size 3, the linear index goes in steps of 4: `collect(diagind(aa)) == [1, 1+4, 1+4+4]`.

Comment: Thanks,phg. I used your method, but it still couldn't work well, can you help me see problem in the following link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966042/julia-error-using-convex-package-with-diagind-function)

Comment: The problem there seems to be specific to another type `Semidefinite` from `Convex`, about which I know nothing.

Comment: congratulations, 10k!

Comment: `diagind` seems to not exist anymore :(

Comment: @igor It has been moved to the now separate module `LinearAlgebra`.