# Julia error using convex package with diagind function

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex

I'm trying to solve the problem

```
d = 0.5 * ||X - \Sigma||_{Frobenius Norm} + 0.01 * ||XX||_{1},
```

where X is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and all the diagnoal element should be 1. XX is same with X except the diagonal matrix is 0. \Sigma is known, I want minimum d with X.

My code is as following:

```
using Convex
m = 5;
A = randn(m, m); 
x = Semidefinite(5);
xx=x;
xx[diagind(xx)].=0;
obj=vecnorm(A-x,2)+sumabs(xx)*0.01;
pro= minimize(obj, [x >= 0]);
pro.constraints+=[x[diagind(x)].=1];
solve!(pro)
```

> MethodError: no method matching diagind(::Convex.Variable)

I just solve the optimal problem by constrain the diagonal elements in matrix, but it seems diagind function could not work here, How can I solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add the optimization problem you're trying to solve in mathematical form?

Comment: d=0.5*||X-\Sigma||_{Frobenius Norm}+0.01*||XX||_{1}, X is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and all the diagnoal  element should be 1. XX is same with X except the diagonal matrix is 0.  \Sigma is known, I want  minimum d with X.

Comment: Ok, I added that to the question, please check whether that is accurate.

Comment: Yes, you understand it  exactly.

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of 1-norm is `||XX||_1` if you define it as `sum(abs(XX))`? As far as I remember, the operator (1,1)-norm would be the maximum of column sums, and the Schatten 1-norm the sum of singular values. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you want:

```
m = 5
Σ = randn(m, m)
X = Semidefinite(m)
XX = X - diagm(diag(X))
obj = 0.5 * vecnorm(X - Σ, 2) + 0.01 * sum(abs(XX))
constraints = [X >= 0, diag(X) == 1]
pro = minimize(obj, constraints)
solve!(pro)
```

For the types of operations:

- `diag` *extracts* the diagonal of a matrix, as a vector
- `diagm` *constructs* a diagonal matrix out of a vector

So, to have `XX` be `X` with zero diagonal, we subtract the diagonal of `X` from it.  And to constrain `X` having diagonal `1`, we *compare* its diagonal with `1`, using `==`.

It is a good idea to keep immutable values as far as possible, instead of trying to modify things. I don't know whether `Convex` even supports that.

Comment: I see that there's also a way to [fix variables](https://convexjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#fixing-and-freeing-variables), maybe you could use that for ensuring your diagonals' values. But I don't really have any experience with optimization packages.